# Edit and continue doesn't work after upgrading to VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

My asp.net solution was working fine in VS2013 but after upgrading to VS2015 all my aspx.cs files have that little padlock icon during run and I can no longer edit the files when debugging.
The 'Edit and Continue' options were previously set (and still is).

Is this a bug or do I need to set something else?

Comment: I am now just about certain there is a bug in VS2015 - suddenly the edit and continue started working, I stopped the app and immediately re-started and E&C was again disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The Edit and Continue setting has moved in VS 2015.  It is now in Tools/Options/Debugging/General.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx for more details.

Comment: Thanks - I know about the setting, I had it enabled and E&C did work but randomly stops working.